# Error in UICollectionView reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

What I do:
rootVC —> modalView1 —> modalView2 —> modalView3 —> dismiss modalView3 to rootVC then reload collectionView

the collectionView is in the rootVC.

This is the code for going back to rootVC:
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

dismissing to rootVC is working but error occurs during collectionView.reloadData()

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the modalView ??

Comment: make sure collectionView IBOutlet connected to interface builder

Comment: How do you "dismiss modalView3 to rootVC"? Show your code

Comment: Can u update your question with your code.

Comment: "modalView1": You mean `modalViewController1`? Also, where is `collectionView` exactly? on `rootVC`?

Answer (score 0):

First, the error message is "found nil", so, in this code, collectionView is nil, you can find the content of collectionView, such as tag, button or label, something in content must do not connect the collectionView.